# How to update field value for multiple already existing items of a specific Sitecore template?

Tags: templates, field, sitecore

In Sitecore 7.2 I have a folder with many items that I need to convert into Buckets. I checked bucketable in Standard Values for that template (as per official documentation), so all new items are coming into bucket but I also need to update that field within almost hundred existing items. Any smart way of doing that?

Also, previously I came across similar case when I required to update disabled field for all existing items of certain template, so may be there is some universal solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I know there are 2 ways of doing that - straightforward with the code, and smart with PowerShell module (if you have one installed). Unfortunately, I do not think there is specific interface in Sitecore Desktop for doing that.

**1.Doing mass update from the C# code:**

```
private void UpdateAllFieldsRecursively(Item parentItem, string templateName, string fieldName, string newValue)
{
    if (parentItem != null)
    {
        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
            foreach (Item childItem in parentItem.Children)
            {
                if (childItem.Fields[fieldName] != null && childItem.TemplateName == templateName)
                {
                    using (new EditContext(childItem))
                    {
                        childItem[fieldName] = newValue;
                    }
                }

                if (childItem.HasChildren)
                {
                    UpdateAllFieldsRecursively(childItem, templateName, fieldName, newValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// and below there is the call to recursive mehod
const string parentNode = "/sitecore/content";
var database = Sitecore.Context.Database;
var parentItem = database.GetItem(parentNode);

UpdateAllFieldsRecursively(parentItem, "Article", "Bucketable", "1");
```

**2.PowerShell ISE**. Execute the following code (you may need to modify that slightly according to your scenario):

```
cd 'master:/sitecore/content'
Get-ChildItem -Recurse . | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -match "Article" -and $_.Fields["Bucketable"] -ne $null } | ForEach-Object {

    $_.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $_.Fields["Bucketable"].Value = "1";
    $_.Editing.EndEdit()
    ""
}
```

This script goes recursively from /sitecore/content and updates Bucketable field for all Article template. Replace those values with whatever you need.

Here is a blog-post describing that: http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/mass-update-of-field-value-for-all-existing-items-of-certain-template-two-ways-of-achieving-result

Answer (score 2):

For your bucket scenario, if I understand you correctly, you just want to update a folder with existing items to be a bucket. It sounds like you have configured it correctly. You don't need to go to each existing item and update the `Bucketable` setting. If you have set it in standard values you just need to Sync the bucket and Sitecore will take care of the rest.

[image]

In terms of bulk-editing items, either of @martin-miles' solutions will work. I would probably opt for the PowerShell approach but keep in mind that it's a sharp tool so it's worth testing your command or script on a smaller dataset before doing a full run. Another option to consider is the [Revolver](http://www.codeflood.net/revolver/) tool. This is an example of changing all descendants below the current directory:

```
find -r (sf bucketable 1)
```